# Linked php files give error

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm using a shared hosting service for my sites and there is a strange situation.

When any php page is accessed from a link (like Google search results page, etc), the page will not open.
The following error is shown:
"Forbidden   you don't have permission to access / on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

If the same url is input directly into the browser, the page displays fine.

The situation is not the same for html extension pages, which open properly from links too.

I am not using any .htaccess file.
Permission for files is 644 (I've never changed anything).

This situation is something new, there was not such a problem in the past.

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: do you do something with referer ? is subdomain correct ?

Comment: I'm not using htaccess file. No redirect. I haven't changed anything.

Comment: then log whole request and compare whats different